# to use Cloudera Hbase , any license required?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

Installed CDH5.8 express , while installing i came across this..

NOTE:Please ensure that you have the appropriate license for Hbase or contact cloudera for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The context of this message is availability of commercial support. Cloudera support for HBase is available through specific product editions.

HBase itself, of course, carries the Apache License and thus is free to use.